# Java loop very strange behaviour

Tags: java, loops

Ho guys, I'm experiencing this strange behaviour in this code:

```
    CubicInterpolation cInterp = new CubicInterpolation(x,y,1);
    int step = 20;
    int xp = (int) cInterp.getXmin();

    int xMax = (int) cInterp.getXmax();

    while(xp <= xMax)
    {
        int xC = xp;
        xp = xp + step;
        double yp = cInterp.interpolate(xC);
        drawPoint(xC, (int) yp, 2); 
    }
```

Let's say before the loop xp = 128; it is incremented in the loop but when the loop finishes for the first time xp is 128 again!! So the loop never ends and I've got a stack overflow.
Can somebody explain me this such strange behaviour? Thanks

Comment: This wouldn't be a stackoverflow, it would be an infinite loop. Your problem is elsewhere. NB: `a = a + b` is usually written as `a += b`.

Comment: Yes first I had xp += step but since I got this error I tried to write it differently

Comment: What are the values of `xp` and `xMax`?

Comment: I don't see any issue in this code snippet. Use a debugger to locate the real issue.

Comment: What is the value of `(int) cInterp.getMmax()` ? Is it possible that `xp + step` actually steps over `Integer.MAX_INT` if `xMax` is equal to or very close to max int?

Comment: Usually xp starts from 80 to 100 and xMax is 400 to 500

Answer (score 0):

Comment out your calls to `interpolate` and `drawPoint` (i.e. the 3rd and 4th line in your while loop) and depending on the values of `xp` and `xMax` your loop will terminate sooner or later. If so, uncomment exactly one of the previously commented two lines and see what happens in both cases.